# to_date function issue in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, to-date

I have a PostgreSQL table with a column name date_stamp and its data type is "date".
I need to execute the below query and it's not working. Can anyone help? Thank You.
(I am using PHP)

```php
$DS = date('d m Y' ,$data['time_stamp']);       

$query = "SELECT id from ".$this->table_ud." WHERE user_id=43 AND date_stamp=to_date(".$DS.",YYYY MM DD)";
```

Comment: Got the answer. The problem was not with PostgreSQL. to_date() works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to use `to_date`.

You could just do with:

```
$DS = date('Y-m-d' ,$data['time_stamp']);       
$query = "SELECT id from ".$this->table_ud." WHERE user_id=43 AND date_stamp='$DS'";
```

Comment: are u sure that    to_date() is not necessary?  Initially I tried to do what you have suggested above and it didn't work. My guess was that php date() function returns a string and the date_stamp column in the table is of type date and that you cannot compare a string type with date.